# HTML file input - lock the file once selected

Tags: javascript, html, file-locking

Is there any way for the browser to "lock" the file after being selected by the `<input type="file" />`? Right now I can select a file, start some operations on it with JavaScript and in the meantime I can delete it from my disk, which results in errors in JavaScript code.

**EDIT** The goal is to make sure the file cannot be deleted while I am working on it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way. Simply because JS is a client side language, even with server side this wouldn't be possible because you can't interact with users computer. For this to happened you would need your desktop app that would take the file for example copy it and lock it.

If this was to be implemented, this would have to be implemented in the browser.

Edit addition:

If you think about it why this isn't implemented in browsers already, maybe because what if you go offline while uploading what will happen to the file? Stay locked?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** : You can create a copy in memory, and use this instead of the file on user's disk.
You will have to read its content first and to create a new File/Blob from there :

```js
let theFile = null;
inp.onchange = async function(e) {
  theFile = await saveBlob(inp.files[0]);
  btn.disabled = false;
  inp.disabled = true;
}
btn.onclick = e => {
  console.log(theFile);
  let reader = new FileReader();
  // to prove it's really still there
  reader.onload = e => console.log(new Uint8Array(reader.result));
  reader.onerror = e => console.log(e);
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(theFile.slice(0, 4));
}

function saveBlob(blob) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
  reader.onload = e => {
    if (blob instanceof File) { 
    // tries to keep it as a File, but beware some implementations still have bugs
      res( new File([reader.result], blob.name, {type: blob.type}) );
    } else {
      res( new Blob([reader.result], {type: blob.type}) );
    }
  };
  reader.onerror = rej; // already removed ???
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
<button id="btn" disabled>I did remove it from disk</button>
```

An alternative way would be to store it in indexedDB.

Then, you can work with this copy and be sure that it will stay in memory, whatever the user does with the original file.

If you need to keep it for longer than the document's life, you can create a blobURI (`URL.createObjectURL(theFile)`) that you'll be able to store in localStorage and retrieve in reload or redirection with `fetch(blobURI).then(r=>r.blob());`.
And if you need it to survive for even longer (an hard refresh will kill the reference of the blobURI), then use indexedDB.

---

**Edit** in response to [question's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46092268/revisions#reve4aadf1f-da2f-41f1-be3b-f5b4f9bf88d3).

Obviously you won't be able to change file's permissions on user's disk, but you don't need to do it, since you can get a copy of it to work with.

Comment: Maybe the question is too vague. My goal was to make sure the file cannot be deleted. Thanks for this anyway.

Comment: @andy250 for what purpose? By keeping it in memory, the File won't be deleted, and you will be able to keep for as long as your session is a alive (to keep it for longer than document's life, you can create a blobURI for the copied Blob) or for even longer in the IndexedDB. If your goal is really to change permissions on the user's disk, then obviously you can't.

Comment: so that user can't delete a file I am working on. Like you are zipping a file on your computer with 7zip and you try to rename/delete it - you can't. I don't want to change file permissions. Just make sure that user can't delete the file until I am done with it. As I said in question - I don't want and I can't store it in memory, It is just wrong and won't even work for files larger than available memory.

Comment: @andy250 "As I said in question ..."* where did you said that? And yes you can store it in memory, for large files, you can store them in indexedDB as I told you. This will create a copy **on disk** in some part only available to the browser. And the *lock* behavior you are talking about is the one of the OS, which allows only a single process to read the file in the same time. It's just because 7-zip has not released the active reading yet that you can't modify it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned it. I see your point with IndexedDB but then again copying let's say a 20GB on disk just to "keep it" is an overkill in my opinion. Also isn't there a limit to IndexedDB size? Bottom line is that I wanted to lock the file, not fiddle with memory or duplicate it. If that's not possible with a browser - so be it.

Comment: @andy250 Are you seriously handling 20GB files? What are you doing with it? As soon as you use a FileReader on it, you will copy it in memory. And I never tried, but I guess that when you do upload it, the OS will lock it automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153923/discussion-between-andy250-and-kaiido).